# How to extract the date value from input type date using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here I want to extract the date value from the above element. and compare it with the today date but it is giving error.

Comment: [`valueAsDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement). _“it is giving error”_ — Which error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this to get today's date:

```
`var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today =  yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
document.write(today);`
```

For the input it will always have the same rendering: "yyyy-mm-dd":

```
var dateControl = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');
dateControl.value = '2017-06-01';
```

So if you edit it in first way in this format you will be able to compare them ;)